# DF.where multiple values

Tags: python

Doing the following :

```
DF.where(DF['Test']=="a" and DF['Test']=="b")
```

throw the error :

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Doing :

```
 DF.where(DF['Test']=="a" & DF['Test']=="b")
```

returns :

```
TypeError: Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [object] array and scalar of type [bool]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

Comment: tl;dr `DF.where((DF['Test']=="a") & (DF['Test']=="b"))`

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych thanks but doing this also throw an error but not the same. Editing my post

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych Please see my edit.

Comment: Have you copied my solution or just replaced the `and` with `&`. Note the brackets in my line around `(DF['Test']=="a")` and `(DF['Test']=="b")`

Comment: Also, you might want to use "or" (i.e. `|`) otherwise the value needs to be both equal to `'a'` and `'b'` at the same time

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych thank you v much. It was a bracket issue ! and it was `|` or which was needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case or condition doesn't make a lot of sense, either you want the events  of A OR B, never A and B (unless it is a string column). And you are filtering it.
In your case I think all you should do is maybe make a isin.

Like the sample

```
df.where[df['test'].isin(['A','B'])
```

Also there is an error in your filter case. You are using Python logical constructor when Pandas logical constructor are & | and ~ like this question show [peta](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html)

**Also, there is a bracket issue :**

```
 DF.where((DF['Test']=="a") & (DF['Test']=="b"))
```

Comment: Hi, upvoted you workaround and also edited your answer by highlighting my mistake. Many thanks, and will accept your answer as soon as i can !